# IDL: How to plot simple 2d plot in iplot

Tags: graph, idl-programming-language

Reading from an example (created 2009), I have created a `.dat` file called `temperature_vs_current.dat` with 2 columns of data. The example says I should then read the file into IDL via

```
IDL> iplot, temperature_vs_darkcurrent.dat
```

but this returns

```
% Expression must be a structure in this context: TEMPERATURE_VS_DARKCURRENT.
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

how should I format my input, and what is the error here? This is IDL Version 6.0

Answer (score 1):

(It follows guesswork derived from [this](http://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/idl/IPLOT.html) and [this](http://nstx.pppl.gov/nstx/Software/IDL/idl_intro.html#PLOT1D).)  Apparently, `iplot` needs array argument(s), not files, so you could try something like this:

```
N = 10                ; number of data pairs in the .dat file
xy = fltarr(2,N)      ; create empty 2xN array
openr, 1, 'temperature_vs_darkcurrent.dat' ; open file
readf, 1, xy          ; file content ~~> array
close, 1              ; close file
x = xy(0,*)           ; separate pairs into x...
y = xy(1,*)           ; ...and y
iplot, x, y           ; iplot
end
```

This is just a starting point, there might be more convenient ways, I have no idea.